# Finding Mismatch of a column having decimal value using Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, mismatch

I have 2 csv files with same headers. I merged them with primary keys. Now from the merged file, I need to create another file with data which has all matching values and mismatch at 7th decimal place for col1 and col2 which are float value columns. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to know if the only the value at the 7th decimal places mismatches, or if the values mismatch when rounded to the 7th decimal place?

Comment: @Boskosnitch... i want to the value only when value at the 7th decimal places mismatches. I have given the dataset example in my below comments

Answer (score 0):

- generate some data that matches shape you note
- simple case of do equality of rounded numbers, then `to_csv()`
- included sample 5 rows

```
from pathlib import Path

b = np.random.randint(1,100, 100)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(b+np.random.uniform(10**-8, 10**-7, 100), columns=["col1"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b+np.random.uniform(10**-8, 10**-7, 100), columns=["col2"])

fn = Path.cwd().joinpath("SO_same.csv")
df1.join(df2).assign(eq7dp=lambda df: df.col1.round(7).eq(df.col2.round(7))).head(5).to_csv(fn)

with open(fn) as f: contents=f.read()
    
print(contents)
```

#### output

```
,col1,col2,eq7dp
0,37.00000005733964,37.00000002893621,False
1,46.00000001386966,46.00000008236663,False
2,99.00000007870301,99.00000007452154,True
3,42.00000001906606,42.00000001278533,True
4,79.00000007529009,79.00000007372863,True
```

#### supplement

In comments you note you want to use a `np.where()` expression, to select **col1** if equal else **False**. You need to ensure that 2nd and 3rd parameters to `np.where()` are compatible.  NB **False** is zero when converted to an int/float.

```
df1.join(df2).assign(eq7dp=lambda df: df.col1.round(7).eq(df.col2.round(7)),
                     col3=lambda df: np.where(df.col1.round(7).eq(df.col2.round(7)),df.col1,np.full(len(df),False))
                    )
```

Comment: i tried this solution, but this did not work for me. Instead this i tried Numpy where method                np.where(df.col1.round(7) == df.col2.round(7), df.col1, False)                                                       but this is giving me an error saying " can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Float' "                         Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Also the round function you used is to round of the decimal place, but in my question, i already have the decimal value for both the columns and i need to compare both the whole part and fractional part. The whole part should be same and the fractional part should be same till 6th decimal place and mismatch at 7th decimal place.

Comment: **data = {'col1' :{00000181.238767789, 00000273.981111765},
        'col2' :{00000181.238767589, 00000273.981111765}
       }**  my resultant dataframe should have the column col3 which has the mismatch value 00000181.238767789

Comment: you are mixing up two mathematical definitions : significant places and decimal places.  *The whole part should be same and the fractional part should be same till 6th decimal place* is decimal places which is what `decimal()` does

Comment: included an supplement for purpose of `np.where()`

Comment: thanks bud. I was able to do that when i tried on a simple smaller dataset, but I still have issue when I use this on actual dataset. Both the columns are of Object datatype and when I try to convert them into Float for the comparison, it says "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' ". I am not able to figured out this error

Comment: I tried like **np.where(df.col1.astype(float).round(7) == df.col2.astype(float).round(7), df.col1, 'False')**